# Docker maven plugin with NONE tag in docker images

Tags: docker

in pom.xml I have defined:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>${docker.image.name}:${docker.image.tag}</imageName>
                <dockerDirectory>${basedir}/target/dockerfile</dockerDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.war</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

when I run:

```
docker ps -a
```

everything seems to by ok:

```
697e4e483ba5        localhost:5000/my-app:latest   "sh -c 'java $JAVA_O…"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:9006->9006/tcp   my-app.1rb406ind3ue1ubb8kzhuaht6.av4yn057f9ata2n2sdslkuwfs
```

but when I run:

```
docker images -a
```

I can see  TAG:

```
localhost:5000/my-app   <none>              ab6ac08baa3a        4 minutes ago       552MB

localhost:5000/my-app   <none>              17acdee85fe9        3 hours ago         549MB
```

is this ok ? How can I add latest tag in images ?

Comment: did you set docker.image.name and docker.image.tag variable names ?

Comment: yes because in docker ps I can see this names

Answer (score 0):

1. maybe you should upgrade your plugin ,latest version is 1.2.0 for now.
2. (this worked for me)add execution into your docker-maven-plugin plugin configuration tag
   like this:

```
<executions>

<execution>
    <id>build-image</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
         <goal>build</goal>
    </goals>
 </execution>
 <execution>
    <id>tag-image</id>
     <phase>package</phase>
     <goals>
         <goal>tag</goal>
     </goals>
     <configuration>
         <image>your.registry.com/${project.name}</image> 
         <newName>your.registry.com/${project.name}:${project.version}</newName>
     </configuration>
 </execution>
</executions>
```

3. execute `mvn package`,then plugin would build and tag your docker image
4. for more info, you could view plugin's github page. there will be a readme.md out there. https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin